# Save and load spritekit images data from/to disk using databse in swift

Tags: sql, swift

I am developing SpriteKit universal iOS application that will contain many spritekit images. I was wondering if there are better methods for working with large amount of data images in iOS apps from what's available as default from Apple (i.e. Core Data). Some resources point out that working with a database, like SQL, to save and load images data to/from a disk, improves the overall app performance in terms of memory resources.

What is the really best way to manage sprites content in the iOS application?

Comment: saving images and data take a look at sdmanager and afnetworking best open source Libraries for disk caching and ram cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData is an object graph management system first, and a front-end to a database second. Its intended use case it to manage models and their relationships to other models, much like tables in SQL. Therefore, it is not the correct solution for persisting binary data, such as an image. Flat file storage is definitely the better choice. Look into [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/) for writing files to disk.

If writing your own disk cache sounds like a daunting task, you should consider using a third-party framework. [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) is a popular image cache written completely in Swift. It also handles fetching images over the Internet and provides extensions for integration with UIKit.

Alternatively, just [search "image cache" on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=image+cache&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) to see plenty of other options.

Comment: What is your opinion about using the Apple's default property lists for storing image configuration data such as locations, patterns, etc.? Will this improve any performance or just makes it easier for data management where sprite can be replaced without code modification. Thanks!

Comment: @saate_group This is completely up to you. It's certainly very helpful if you're storing the data in your app bundle and want to change it regularly. It can also be very helpful if someone else on your team needs to update the file and is not themselves a developer.

Comment: ...now, if you're talking about downloading the p-list data over the internet, be wary. A p-list *can* be fetched, then deserialized with [NSPropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/index.html), but you should probably consider a more widely adopted spec like JSON. Furthermore, if you want to fetch JSON data, and then store the data to a p-list on disk, this is also possible. Just deserialize with NSJSONSerialization and re-serialize with NSPropertyListSerialization.

Comment: No intention on my end to download p-list over the internet. This app will not depend on the internet connection for image downloading nor use. It is a game app and images will not be loaded regularly after release. Besides what you have said in terms of the p-list use, it really will not help in terms of the app performance improvement such as memory usage. Correct?

Comment: In most cases, I would say you definitely *do not* get any sort of memory benefit from storing configuration data in a p-list. You will have to load this data into memory at some point in order to use it. Furthermore, you actually *lose* a small bit of CPU & timing performance when you have to read a p-list file from disk. It takes way longer to read data from disk than from memory. For practical purposes, I would not worry too much about performance until you are *actually observing* performance problems. [The first rule of Optimization is: Don't](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization).

Comment: Thanks. This info helped going forward. The art assets are the best managed in sprite kit using texture atlases to achieve best app performance.